# Rxjs: How to cascading an array of multiple dependant call

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a scenario where I need to send multiple calls in GET and DELETE and after make a final call.

In other words I have an array of objects to insert (*array2insert*) by calling a http POST an array of objects (*array2delete*) to be deleted with http DELETE and finally call http GET.

I tried something like this but it doesn't work

```js
forkJoin(
  from(array2insert).mergeMap(),
  from(array2insert).mergeMap()
).pipe(lastGetCall)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want something like the following,
which I haven't tried to actually compile:

```
 forkJoin([
    from(array2insert).pipe(
      concatMap(item => this.httpClient.post(`/api/foo`, item))
    ),
    from(array2delete).pipe(
      concatMap(item => this.httpClient.delete(`/api/foo/${item.id}`)
    ),
    this.httpClient.get(`/api/bar`)
  ])
```

Comment: I tried this solution which seems the most readable but the requests are not performed all and go in "canceled"

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, that should be almost working. Make sure you are subscribing during testing otherwise you wont see any output.

I tried the following and it seems to do what you want:

```js
const wait = num =>
    of(num).pipe(
        tap(() => console.log("Making call: ", num)),
        delay(100)
    );

forkJoin(
    from([1, 2, 3]).pipe(mergeMap(wait)),
    from([4, 5, 6]).pipe(mergeMap(wait))
)
    .pipe(mergeMap(() => wait("doGet")))
    .subscribe(() => {});
```

The only difference is the mergeMap in the pipe following the forkJoin.